# What libraries are needed to install Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, compiling, dependencies, python3

When trying to install python 3.7 on Ubuntu 18.04

I get error messages like:

> zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

or

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

or

> ~/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin/python-build: line 775: make: command not found

or

> configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Comment: How did you try to install Python? Compiling from upstream sources?

Comment: I was using pyenv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://bugs.python.org/issue31652#msg321260

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the wiki at the `pyenv` project's repo on GitHub. [Common build problems from `pyenv` wiki](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems)

> Make sure to follow this guidance for your platform before any troubleshooting.
>
> Ubuntu/Debian:
>
> ```bsh
> sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev \
> libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev \
> xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl git
> ```
>
> Alternative of libreadline-dev:
>
> `sudo apt install libedit-dev`

Build dependencies on other distros are included in the wiki as well.